# Continuous same char list and I cannot delete all of them

Tags: c#

When I want to delete my specific char which is "o" in list in this code it delete some of them and others it does not delete. I mean when I debug it the result is (Roazooooor). I want to delete all of "o" chars not half of them
and when I debug it, I want it to give me (razr) without "o".

```
    namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string name = "Rooazoooooooooor";
            var nameChar = new List<char>();
            nameChar.AddRange(name);
            for (int i = 0; i < nameChar.Count; i++)
            {
                if (nameChar[i] == 'o')
                    nameChar.Remove(nameChar[i]);
                Console.Write(nameChar[i]);

            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: this is what happen when I debug it]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you remove an item, you're then moving onto the next index, even though you'll have shuffled everything after that item up one.

In this particular case, the simplest option would be to use `string.Replace` first:

```
name = name.Replace("o", "");
var nameChar = new List<char>(name);
```

Or you could keep your existing code and use:

```
while (nameChar.Remove('o')) ;
```

Or

```
nameChar.RemoveAll(c => c == 'o');
```

All of these would leave you with a list without any 'o' elements.

For absolute minimal changes in your current code, you could change your loop to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nameChar.Count; i++)
{
    if (nameChar[i] == 'o')
    {
        // After removing the element at index i,
        // we want to try index i again, so decrement
        // and continue without printing.
        nameChar.Remove(nameChar[i]);
        i--;
        continue;
    }
    Console.Write(nameChar[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to use List in your case? If not then:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string name = "Rooazoooooooooor";
        string resultName = string.Empty;
        foreach (var currentChar in name)
        {
            if (currentChar != 'o')
                resultName += currentChar;
        }
        Console.Write(resultName);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

`